# Differential equation in chemical reaction application

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, python

I need help in solving this ivp differential equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = k(a-x)^2 (b-\frac{x}{2})$$

$a=0.0010$

$b =0.0041$

$k=7.13x10^3$

with ivp $x(0) = 0$

by python solution, the answer should be

[image]

by manually solve the equation before substitute it with ivp, i get this

[image]

Am I on the right track, because if I replace with the ivp value, $x(0)=0$ to get C value, I get different answer as python

I'm stuck in solving this, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's separable...

Comment: i've done it, and after substitute with x(0)=0, i got c = 18.865, but it is contradict with the python solution

Comment: What do you mean with $c$?

Comment: I've updated the post, after i get the solution as I've done it manually, i should replace with the ivp value which is x=0 and t=0 to get the value of c, but when I done it, i got different answer in c value, is my manual solution answer is right

Comment: The two are the same. The first three terms on the right hand side of the equal sign are $-c$

Comment: can you please elaborate more. sorry I cant understand

Comment: Your solution and Python's solution are the same. If you use the logarithm laws (like $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b))$ you see it more clearly.

Comment: so to get the value of c, i just need to subs the value of t and x in 2nd picture with value 0 according to the ivp problem, am i right

Comment: You said you already computed $c$, so why ask again? Your $c$ and Python's $c$ are the same after you rewrite your solution according to the logarithms laws as mentioned above.

Comment: ah.. yes finally i got it, thks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = k(a-x)^2 \left(b-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

is separable we have

$$
-\frac{2 ((a-x) \log (x-2 b)+(x-a) \log (x-a)+a-2 b)}{k (a-2 b)^2 (a-x)}=t+c_0
$$

or

$$
\frac{1}{2} k (a-2 b)^2 (t+c_0)+\frac{a-2 b}{a-x}-\log (x-a)+\log (x-2 b)=0
$$

or

$$
e^{\frac{a-2 b}{a-x}}\frac{x-2b}{x-a}-e^{-\frac{1}{2} k (a-2 b)^2 (t+c_0)}=0
$$

now making $(t=0, x=0)$ we have

$$
e^{\frac{a-2 b}{a}}\frac{2b}{a}-e^{-\frac{1}{2} k (a-2 b)^2 c_0}=0
$$

so

$$
c_0 = \frac{2 \log \left(\frac{a e^{\frac{2 b}{a}-1}}{2 b}\right)}{k (a-2 b)^2}
$$